# How to parse JSON String using jQuery while do not know the exactly keys of it?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm now writing a test html program to check well-formed JSON data send by web socket, and i'm stuck here:

parsing JSON String while I do not know the exactly keys of it.

jQuery.parseJSON() can return the resulting JavaScript object, but I need to know each key to  access the data.

I may not make my question clearified, sorry 'bout that.What I want is to make data more readable instead of a long JSON String.

Comment: This is a chicken and egg problem. What do you want us to tell you? If you need to know the keys, then you need to know the keys; otherwise, why do you need to know the keys? If you _just_ want to know whether the JSON is strictly well-formed, well [`parseJSON` may throw an exception if it's not](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) (no word yet on what "may" means here).

Comment: I may not make my question clearified, sorry 'bout that.What I want is to make data more readable instead of a long JSON String.

Comment: Yeah that seems like a totally different question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(i in json) {
 console.log(i);
 console.log(json[i]);
}
```

Is this construct of any use?

As others have pointed out, you could use the jQuery .each() to iterate over it as well.

Comment: What if it's a Nested JSON String?

Comment: You can probably test what the first character is "{" or otherwise and make a first approximation guess about whether to do another loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate throw all the keys in the json object.

Ex:

```
$.each({'key':'value'}, function(i, v) { 
    console.log(i, v)
});
```